# Toolbar pushing Status bar away

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, toolbar, statusbar

I've got a problem with my status bar which gets pushed away from my toolbar.

I wanted to have the function that when the user scrolles the `ListView` down, the toolbar disappears behind the status bar so that only the tabs are visible, just like in the WhatsApp and YouTube apps.

To achieve this effect or to get this function I used this line:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

into my `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, but know as I said before, the status bar gets gets pushed away.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it. Simply remove the line:

```
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

from the coordinator layout. You can have that in layouts further down within the ViewPager but at the top level it seems to cause that issue.

Comment: When I tried this solution the status bar turns white semi transparent, is there anything more to do?